# How to configure kDiff3 as merge tool for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, svn, kdiff3

I have been loosing code due to poor merging built in to Android Studio (using SVN for source control) how can I configure kDiff3 as the merge tool which Android Studio will use for diff and merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is simple like in Visual Studio or Eclipse.

File > Settings... > Tools > Diff > External Diff Tools

- Tick the check box "User external diff tool"
- Path to executable:
  {Program Files}**\KDiff3\Kdiff3.exe**
- Parameters: **%3 --L1 "Base" %2
  --L2 "Theirs" %1 --L3 "Mine"**
- Tick the check box "User external merge tool"
- Path to executable:
  {Program Files}**\KDiff3\Kdiff3.exe**
- Parameters: **-m %3 --L1 "Base"
  %2 --L2 "Theirs" %1 --L3 "Mine" -o %4**

[image: screen shot of kDiff3 settings in Android Studio]

Comment: Did the exact same thing, but `git mergetool` still opens `vimdiff` in terminal.